# Unknown startup program gpfynawk

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

What is gpfynawk? The popup always appears on my laptop screen. I already searched on Google but I couldn't find it.

[image]

Asus laptop. Windows 10.

Comment: Not a known program. Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag its targeting icon over this message. This will tell you the name of the process and its folder. [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1620086/edit) your answer and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on it and click "Open file location" then right click on it again and click "End task". Then return to explorer and delete that file.

Comment: When recommending deleting files you might provide the reason why. Not every strangely labeled programm is doing harm.

Comment: I am useing windows  for many years.. And I didnt see a program like this.. It may be malware, trojan, virus.. And you must look where is that program too.. You can determine if it is useful for you or not.. If you cant then take your computer to Help Desk

Comment: And Also I see icon of that application is default Visual Studio Icon.. So it is basic unuseful app and likely harmful app written by untrusted one..

Comment: And User says google didnt find anything with that name.. Are these reasons enough to delete file ?